# Unable to dynamically render a Facebook embedded post in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m038p8f0/4/)

[Facebook Embedded Post Document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts)

I cannot get iframe to work in jsfiddle but hope you can understand the code. I'm trying to load a facebook post dynamically. I read that `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById(idName));` is the way to go to specially render a single post, so that the function doesn't have to render all embedded posts on the page over and over again when a new post is dynamically created.

But I cannot get that to work. The only way I can get that to render is `FB.XFBML.parse();`, but that seems not to be an ideal way of doing that for just rendering a specific post. Can anyone figure out what's the problem with `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById(idName));`?

```
var facebookScriptId = 'facebook-jssdk';
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.2";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', facebookScriptId));

$('button').click(function(){

    var id = $('span').text(),
        idName = 'fb'+id;

    $('div').replaceWith('<div id="'+idName+'" class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/'+id+'"></div>')

    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById(idName));

})

<button>Click</button>
<div></div>
<span>10152128760693553</span>
```

Comment: Calling `FB.XFBML.parse()` will not actually _render_ all social plugins again; it will only go through your whole document again to _find_ all tags that are used to embed any of the social plugins, and then render only those that have not been rendered yet – so unless your document is massive, the impact of that should not be felt at all. // The problem here is likely that `document.getElementById` doesn’t find the element, because it has not been put into the DOM yet by your previous `$('div').replaceWith()` call. Using `setTimeout` to “de-couple” those two operations might help here.